# How to test if the query is taking a longer period of time as our production database is growing?

Tags: mysql, performance, php, testing, query-performance

I would like to have a test (read: whatever can send a mail) in which whenever our query is taking more than **2 seconds** to execute, it will send to me an email. If it matters we are using cakePhp with CircleCi and PhPUnit. We have also three databases, first is production, second one is development and the third one is test_database.

What is the best approach to this problem ? Is there a app which can test this ?